# Implicit and explicit validator param --entrypoint cause different result of gossip_service discovering

Tags: validator, entrypoint

I am trying to set up a private cluster of Solana, after executing ./multinode-demo/bootstrap-validator.sh, it's running and running without stop..., while i am waiting, I tried to start another validator by running ./multinode-demo/validator-x.sh on the same machine. but the gossip service discovery result depends on implicit and explicit public IP address for entrypoint:
if I run ./multinode-demo/validator-x.sh  the response will be discovering failed as follows:
[image: with explicit host IP address]

but if i execute only ./multinode-demo/validator-x.sh, without any IP address specified, the response will be successful discovery as follows:
[image: without host IP address, means implicit local address]

Anyone can tell me what I missed or the root cause of this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: correct the first case/screenshot: ./multinode-demo/validator-x.sh <host ip addr>

Comment: I know the answer and solved it. the cause is my cloud server does not allow port 8000-10000 open by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if the port 8000-10000 are open(allow access through) of the bootstrap validator server(the host ip addr).

Comment: elaborate this answer by explaining how you discovered that the ports were not open so others can identify this issue if they experience it

Comment: ok, compared to correct discovery result for the case of no ip addr specified, the incorrect output for explicitly providing ip addr confused me for several days. In despair, I decided went through documentation carefully, at validating section (https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-reqs#required), I suddenly realized I was not sure if those ports are open or not although no any log info mentioned that. then I checked my cloud server and added some security rules to explicitly open them in case they are closed by default and it worked. So good documentation is very important. :-)